# Transform $f(x)$ to time based function $f(t)$

Tags: functions, transformation

I have a function of $(x,y)$ , for example $y = mx +c$,

And I also have a function for velocity in time manner, for example $v = 2t$

Basically I want to draw $f(x)$ in some delta time $t_0 - t_1$ with speed $v(t)$. So if $v(t)$ is quadratic function, I'll have an acceleration in drawing the $f(x)$

So, how do I get $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ ??

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking. What is $f(x)$, is it $y$? Do you mean that $f(x)$ travels with velocity $v$ and if so, what does this really mean?

Comment: yes, $y = f(x)$. Imagine a point travel from $x_0,y_0$ to $x_1,y_1$ along $f(x)$ path with speed $v(t)$. I'd like to decide that point's position for each $t$

Comment: If the point is moving in the plane (both $x,y$ coordinates change with time $t$), then velocity (and acceleration) are vector quantities.  If *speed* is known, then your problem requires parameterizing the curve $y=f(x)$ by arclength, so that position along the curve can be identified from distance (arclength) travelled.

Comment: yes, arclength solves everything. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance along the curve $y$ starting from $x=x_0$ is

$$S(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \sqrt{1+y'^2} dx$$

If the particle travels with velocity $v(t)$ along $y$ starting from $x_0$ then

$$S(x) = \int_0^t v(t') dt'$$

defines $x(t)$ implicitly (and $y(t) = f(x(t))$).

For example if $y = x$ and $v = at$ then

$$S(x) = \sqrt{2}(x-x_0) = \frac{at^2}{2}$$

so

$$x(t) = x_0 + \frac{at^2}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: great, I don't consider using arclength